# how to override data in core data ? how to solve duplicate data in Core Data?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, xcode, swift

I am fetching data from a server and then I save all of the data to Core Data. 
But when I save it, it creates multiple copies(duplicate data).

My questions are :

1. How to handle duplicate data in Core Data?
2. How to save override data using Swift in CoreData?

Comment: Hi Dim San Cing!  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried?  What errors do you get?  Please explain your issue a bit more and what you have tried and on what platform so we have a better chance at accurately answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save new data in core data, you can delete all records from the core data and then you can save all record in core data.

Here is function to delete all record from core data. you can call this function before saving records in core data.

```
 func deleteEverything()
 {
    let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let coord = appDel.persistentStoreCoordinator

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Categorytbl") // Your entity name
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *)
    {
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        do
        {
            try coord.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: context)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        do{
            let fetchedObjects : NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            if(fetchedObjects.count > 0)
            {
                for currObj in fetchedObjects
                {
                    context.deleteObject(currObj as! NSManagedObject)
                }
                let _ : NSError! = nil
                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Error in Deletion : \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I had a same issue. Its working fine at my end.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXAMPLE :  

 let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Theater")
    var array =  [Theater]()
    fetchReq.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let obj = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq) as!  [Theater]
        for  details:Theater in obj{


            array.append(details)
            print(details.movies)
        }

    } catch {
        print("Error in Fetching")
        return nil
    }
```

You have Store objet in Array

now

```
    let obj:Theater = array[0] as! Theater
    //Update Record 
  do {
        try obj.managedObjectContext?.save()
    } catch {
        print("Exception")
    }
```

Will Update Record